# How to simulate non-linear regression model with splines?

Tags: r, regression, splines, nonlinear

I want to simulate a non linear regression model of the type

$$y_i = 1 + x_i + bs(x_i)+ e_i,$$

$i=1,...,1000$, where $bs(x_i)$ is a b-spline. I have tried to use the `splines` R package but when I try to fit the non linear regression model, the estimate of one of the entries of the spline is `NA`, and the rest of the estimates are far from the true value:

```
library(splines)

n = 1000
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(n)

bsx <- bs(x)
eps <- rnorm(n,0,0.25)

y = 1 + x + bsx[,1] + bsx[,2] + bsx[,3] + eps

des <- cbind(x,bsx)

lm(y~ des)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ des)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         desx         des1         des2         des3  
     1.6017       1.1633       0.5384       0.2188           NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a start, emulate the examples on the help page.  Type `?bs`.

Comment: @whuber thanks.

Comment: Try regressing `lm(x~bsx)` and see what happens... `x` is already captured as a linear combination of the columns of `bsx`, so you don't need to have it in the regression.

Comment: @jbowman Did you mean `lm(y~bsx)`? If so, this works! I could accept that as an answer.

Comment: I actually meant `x`; the point was to show the collinearity between the variables in `des`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that `x` is implicitly captured in the variables returned by the `bs` function, so adding it as a separate regressor results in perfect multicollinearity.

To see this, we can calculate the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of `des`"

```
> eigen(cov(des))$values
[1] 1.024286e+00 7.888118e-03 1.515617e-03 1.098538e-18
```

where the smallest eigenvalue is effectively zero.   Leaving out `x` results in:

```
> eigen(cov(bsx))$values
[1] 0.0320042724 0.0060866427 0.0009164426
```

so the issue is evidently the addition of the column `x` to the columns of `bsx`.

Running the regression without `x` results in:

```
> summary(lm(y~bsx))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ bsx)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.78588 -0.15857  0.00394  0.16535  0.71671 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.34905    0.09557  -24.58   <2e-16 ***
bsx1         3.09459    0.20696   14.95   <2e-16 ***
bsx2         5.33126    0.09630   55.36   <2e-16 ***
bsx3         7.66870    0.15867   48.33   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.245 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9554,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9552 
F-statistic:  7109 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

... a much more useful result!